# How to avoid background erasing when drawing lines?

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

I'm writing a paint app.

When drawing a line in CGContext, the background with the size of the bounding box of the line is always got erased - the underlying lines in that box will be cleared.

How to avoid the background erasing?

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] Better: see [How to draw a line on top of an image when finger moves on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320521/how-to-draw-a-line-on-top-of-an-image-when-finger-moves-on-iphone). If your image is added as a background specifically, not directly to the view, it will do what you're looking for.

[original] Keep everything you've drawn already, and redraw it in every call to `drawRect` via `setNeedsDisplay`.

Or, set your `UIView` containing the line to `UIColor clearColor`.